# sharepoint web api returns a link not the value

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to use the Sharepoint 2013 restful web-api to get data from a sharepoint datasheet. For most columns I get the value I want but for one column I am only getting a link.
Any ideas on how I can get the value and not the link? I can make a request to have the sharepoint datasheet changed if that can help but I don't have access to it directly. I have tried with both SOAP UI and Chrome and get the same result.

This is the simplified Restful GET
http://xxxxx.xxx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/XXXXUserRegistry?$select=XXXXUsername

And here is a portion of the response with the link to the data I want.

```
<link rel="edit" title="XXXXUserRegistryItem" href="XXXUserRegistry(1600)"/>
<link     rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/XXXUsername"     type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="XXXXUsername" href="XXXXUserRegistry(1600)/XXXXUsername"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example `XXXXUsername` is so called *navigation property*. According to [4.2 Representing a Navigation Property](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/json-verbose-format/):

> A navigation property represents a reference from a source entity to
>   zero or more other entities.
>
> There are two representations for a navigation property: deferred and
>   expanded. The deferred representation represents each related entity
>   with a URI. The expanded representation represents each related entity
>   with its expanded contents.
>
> By default, a service SHOULD represent each navigation property in the
>   deferred format. This conserves resources.
>
> A client MAY request that a navigation property be expanded, using a
>   combination of $expand and $select. The service MUST represent each
>   navigation property so requested in the expanded format.

So, in order to retrieve `XXXXUsername` value, apply `$expand` query option to the query as demonstrated below:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/XXXUserRegistry?$select=XXXXUsername&$expand=XXXXUsername
```